# Make SQL query for defining of items which are subitems of sentence

Tags: sql, performance

Conditional task description:

I have huge list of `rules`. For example:
Rules:

- 'ell' → rule 1
- 'ity' → rule 2
- e.t.c

I have `sentence`. For example: "Work well"

I need to find all `rules`, which contains as substrings in `sentence`.
E.g
`rule 1` contains in word "well" of our test `sentence`

Note: I know about the word `LIKE` from `SQL`. It helps to find substring among table items.
but I have opposite, my table items are substrings of some sentence.

I have only one idea how to do this.

```
// Iterate through rules list and check
if (sentence.contans(rule[i])) {
    // this rule is interesting for app
}
```

So, such way is workable, but I have huge amount of rules, and sentences
I do not like to loop over huge lists.
I will be glead and thankfull to know, how to make this only via SQL.
Or maybe someone knows better solution, then my solution with brute force.
Thanks.

Comment: Use case statement in SQL or Conditional Split in SSIS. Whats is your data source ?

Comment: @BHouse My data source is ORM in Android. By I have prepared a question in general, without specifying of environment details. Thanks, I will check you proposition.

Comment: If you are using an obfuscation layer (aka ORM) then you are apparently not looking for a SQL solution, but something in Java, correct?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. This question is interesting for me in general. I would like to know how to do this via SQL. Then I will look for a possibility to achieve this in the specific environment.